# Displaying one item from an xml file and dispalying it c#

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I am creating an app for windows phone and i am searching the lyrics and need to display the data from the xml. 
Now i know how to do this for many items in listbox, 
but the xml data i receive is only ever going to have one option. 
http://lyrics.wikia.com/api.php?artist=pharrell%20williams&song=happy&fmt=xml
There is an example of the xml i am trying to parse and display.

So any idea/ tips on how i would go around just parsing this one entry and displaying it to the textbox.
the only thing i am after is the lyrics data and the URL as that's all i will be displaying on the page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use linq-to-xml to query specific information from xml. Following is an example to get lyrics and url using linq-to-xml :

```
var doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
var lyrics = doc.Root.Element("lyrics").Value;
var url = doc.Root.Element("url").Value;
```

With that, lyrics and url information extracted and ready to be displayed in textbox or any other control of choice.
Note: `xml` is xml string downloaded from link in the question.

Comment: Side note - usually it's better to cast element to string instead of accessing it's Value property: `(string)doc.Root.Element("url")`. Because if element was not found you will get exception, but casting will simply return null. Of course, if value is required, then fail-fast way is better